# how handle dependencies between CustomElement

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I have made several CustomElement, like buttons, drawer etc...

The drawer depends on buttons.

With javascript import / export modules dependencies are resolved by the browser and the js files needed are loaded, but with CustomElement their is no import of the others CustomElements needed as they are defined via customElements.define('my-drawer', Drawer);

How do you handle those dependencies ? do you add fake import export so that the browser resolve the dependencies for you? or do you bundle them together even if they may not be all needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the child component into the parent and check if custom element exists before defining it so you won't get an error for multiple custom elements with the same name.

In button.js (assuming is the child):

> if(!customElements.get('my-button')) customElements.define('my-button')

In drawer.js (parent) just import the button.js

Answer (score 0):

you import those dependencies and register those elements; for each once imported and registered any instance of an element becomes 'defined' and the class code exercised, that's why my-complex imports them in the example below; they only need to be imported once, importing more doesn't hurt anything, that's why every class that has dependencies imports them, and that's why each class self-registers, to manage the boilerplate;

```
// my-button.js
export default class MyButton extends HTMLElement{}
customemElements.get('my-button') ?? customElements.define('my-button', MyButton);

// my-thing.js
export default class MyThing extends HTMLElement{}
customemElements.get('my-thing') ?? customElements.define('my-thing', MyThing);


// my-complex.js
import './my-thing.js';
import './my-button.js';
export default class MyComplex extends HTMLElement{}
// use <my-button> and <my-thing> anywhere, including here
customemElements.get('my-complex') ?? customElements.define('my-complex', MyComplex);
```

don't worry about any optimizations, ES modules do that for you, and if you bundle let the bundler handle it--it's not worth considering; just add all the imports each feature needs; ESM does the rest of the work--which together with serviceworkers and caching is a beautiful, easy evolution of the platform; we can actually get away from complex build processes and let the browser do it's job